# Use Ampscript to change font style based on data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, css

I would like to set the font color to green, black or red based on a data extension. The data extension passes a text string such as:

"Status is active."

"Status will expire soon."

"Status is expired."

I want to look in the data extension for the word active, soon or expired and then set the corresponding color.

`<p style="color:__;">@status</p>`

Comment: Such as or is one of the following three texts?

Comment: Yes, it would be one of the three. Active = Green, soon = black, expired = red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [IF condition statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm#using-if-syntax) and assign the colour to a variable then inline the value in the style attribute of your p (or similar) tag. This code assumes your status value from the DE is available as a Data Extension attribute, otherwise use a lookup.

```
%%[
VAR @color, @status, @msg
SET @status = AttributeValue("status_field")

IF @status == "active" THEN
    SET @color = "#00ff00"  /*green*/
    SET @msg = "Status is active."
ELSEIF  @status == "soon" THEN
    SET @color = "#000000"  /*black*/
    SET @msg = "Status will expire soon."
ELSEIF  @status == "expired" THEN
    SET @color = "#ff0000"  /*red*/
    SET @msg = "Status is expired."
ELSE
    SET @color = "#0000ff"  /*default to blue*/
    SET @msg = "Status is not set."
ENDIF
]%%

<p style="color:%%=v(@color)=%%;"> %%=v(@msg)=%% </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.